# Request failed SOAP WS returned code 404

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to consume the following soap url:

> http://89.221.253.174:8080/OpenClinica-ws/ws/data/v1/dataWsdl.wsdl

I am using google pass script and my code looks as below:

```
    var xml = 
          "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
      +"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:v1=\"http://openclinica.org/ws/studySubject/v1\" xmlns:bean=\"http://openclinica.org/ws/beans\">"
      +"<soapenv:Header>"
      +"<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">"
      +"<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=\"UsernameToken-27777511\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">"
      +"<wsse:Username>x</wsse:Username>"
      +"<wsse:Password>y</wsse:Password>"
      +"</wsse:UsernameToken>"
      +"</wsse:Security>"
      +"</soapenv:Header>"
      +"<soapenv:Body>"
      +"<v1:importRequest>"
      +"<ODM>"
      +"<ClinicalData StudyOID=\"S_PROSPER2\" MetaDataVersionOID=\"v1.0.0\">"
      +"<SubjectData SubjectKey=\"SS_UU001\">"
      +"<StudyEventData StudyEventOID=\"SE_QUESW4\" StudyEventRepeatKey=\"0\">"
      +"<FormData FormOID=\"F_RANDANDQUEST_11\">"
      +"<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID=\"IG_RANDA_UNGROUPED\" ItemGroupRepeatKey=\"1\" TransactionType=\"Insert\">"
      +"<ItemData ItemOID=\"I_RANDA_RAND01\" Value=\"1\"/>"
      +"<ItemData ItemOID=\"I_RANDA_RAND02\" Value=\"1\"/>"
      +"<ItemData ItemOID=\"I_RANDA_RAND03\" Value=\"1\"/>"
      +"<ItemData ItemOID=\"I_RANDA_RAND04\" Value=\"1\"/>"
      +"</ItemGroupData>"
      +"</FormData>"
      +"</StudyEventData>"
      +"</SubjectData>"
      +"</ClinicalData>"
      +"</ODM>"
      +"</v1:importRequest>"
      +"</soapenv:Body>"
      +"</soapenv:Envelope>";

var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "contentType" : "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        "payload" : xml
      };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://89.221.253.174:8080/OpenClinica-ws/ws/data/v1/dataWsdl.wsdl", options);
  Logger.log(result);
```

I don't know actually what is the error on here, what does 404 means in this case? Seems like I am communicating with the server but something else is missing.

Any idea what would be wrong in here?

PS: The same code works just fine using soapUI.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by puting all the xml in one line this way:

```
var xml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:v1=\"http://openclinica.org/ws/data/v1\"><soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=\"UsernameToken-27777511\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\"><wsse:Username>x</wsse:Username><wsse:Password>y</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><v1:importRequest><ODM><ClinicalData StudyOID=\"S_PROSPER2\" MetaDataVersionOID=\"v1.3.0\"><SubjectData SubjectKey=\"SS_UU001\"><StudyEventData StudyEventOID=\"SE_QUESW4\" StudyEventRepeatKey=\"0\"><FormData FormOID=\"F_RANDANDQUEST_11\"><ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID=\"IG_RANDA_UNGROUPED\" ItemGroupRepeatKey=\"1\" TransactionType=\"Insert\"><ItemData ItemOID=\"I_RANDA_RAND01\" Value=\"1\"/></ItemGroupData></FormData></StudyEventData></SubjectData></ClinicalData></ODM></v1:importRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
```

I have no idea why is this way it works, but it is working!